# Update values in one table base on conditions in both tables being met MySqL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, and I want to update data in one table based on conditions in both tables being satisfied.

Table 1 is called `employee` and contains the fields `staffId`,`forename`, `surname` and `grade`.  Table 2 is called `competence` and contains the fields `compId`, `staffId`, `groupId`, `subGroupId`, `skillLevel` and `skillUpdate`.  The common field is `staffId`.

The field `skillLevel` can be a value from 0 to 5 and I want to reduce this to 3 when anyone at 'Graduate' grade has set this to 4 or 5. How can I do that?

Comment: What language? PHP? Java/Android? There are so many languages with MySQL so you ahve to be mroe specific if you want answers

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question properly then try something like this and let me know. :P

```
UPDATE competence AS a
INNER JOIN employee AS b ON a.staffId = b.staffId
SET a.skillLevel = 3 
WHERE b.grade LIKE 'Graduate' AND a.skillLevel IN (4,5)
```